# Send mail query results add content from separate table column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sendmail

I have this query that works correctly, but the users want the customer's name in addition to the customer number and ship to the name resides in a separate customers table and would be found using the combination of customer number and ship to number. I.e., look up the combination of customer number and ship to number, to select the ship to name field, between the current shiptoid and itemcode.

```
 EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
 @recipients=N'user@example.com',
 @body= 'Credits Over 20',
 @subject = 'Credits Over 20',
 @profile_name = 'SWFADmin',
 @execute_query_database='MMDC',
 @query_result_separator='',
 @query = 'Select Credits.TransactionNumber, Credits.RepNumber, Credits.CustomerID, Credits.ShipToId, Credits.ItemCode, Credits.Quantity, Credits.UnitMeasure, Credits.ReasonCode, Credits.ReceivedDate, Credits.TransmitStatus from (select TransactionNumber from Credits
 group by TransactionNumber
 having SUM (Quantity)>20) as creditsa

 Inner join Credits on Credits.TransactionNumber=creditsa.TransactionNumber

 where ReceivedDate > DateADD (day, -1, GetDate() )

 Order by transactionnumber, ReceivedDate',

 @attach_query_result_as_file=1
```

Comment: SO do the join on customer table with `customerID` and `shiptonumber`

Comment: I tried changing the current join but it negates the select statement above it I assume because it is nested. How would I add an as ___ after the where clause and inner join from there?

Comment: I figured this out starting from scratch added just the query above

Comment: If your recent edit shows how you solved it, please roll that back and post it as an answer instead, then mark the answer as accepted so that this question no longer comes up as unresolved.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I redid the query from scratch using some hints here and this is what I ended up with....thanks for everyones help.

```
 Select Credits.TransactionNumber,Credits.RepNumber,Credits.CustomerID,Credits.ShipToId,Customers.SHIP_TO_NAME,Credits.ItemCode,Items.DESCRIPTION, Credits.Quantity,Credits.UnitMeasure,Credits.ReasonCode, Credits.ReceivedDate  from (select TransactionNumber from Credits
 group by TransactionNumber
 having SUM (Quantity)>20) as creditsa
 Inner join Credits on Credits.TransactionNumber=creditsa.TransactionNumber
 Inner join Customers on Credits.CustomerId=customers.CUSTOMER_ID and Credits.ShipToId=Customers.SHIP_TO_ID
 Inner join Device_Items on Credits.ItemCode=Items.ITEM_CODE
 where ReceivedDate > DateADD (day, -1, GetDate() )
 Order by RepNumber,transactionnumber,CustomerId, SHIP_TO_ID, ReceivedDate
```